# Bind Super Key to Task View in Windows 11

Tags: windows, ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, windows-11

In recent weeks I have been using Ubuntu a lot with the Gnome interface, and I've come to really appreciate the feature equivalent to the task view on Windows, where you get an overview of all open applications when pressing the super key.
Is there any way to bind the super key natively to open the task view in Windows?
I know I could just bind a macro to it, but I wonder if there is a way in Windows to set this up.

Comment: By the super key, do you mean the Windows key? As there are two such keys, you may re-purpose one, but leave one working as intended.

Comment: Yes, I mean the Windows key, though I do not like that term as a Linux user :b
On my keyboard there's only one super key, how would I go about changing its function?

Comment: You shouldn't! It's a very important key in Windows, therefore its name. Much better to learn how to use Windows as Windows, not as Linux. Map another key.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question! I want to know if it is possible, not if I should or shouldn't do it. Also, the super key obviously isn't called the windows key because it is more important in Windows than in any other OS/desktop environment, but because Windows is used by more users.